# Нерекурсивный обход директорий

Tags: python

Мне нужно нерекурсивно обойти директорию и получить из нее список папок и файлов. Я нашел пример, но что-то у меня он не работает.

```
recursive = 0

dst_sav = "D:\\savorsk"
src = "D:\\Project\\2014\\archdata"

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(src):  
    if not recursive:  
        while len(dirs) > 0:  
            dirs.pop()
            print dirs
```

recursive = 0 это я уже дописал сам т.к. очевидно, что тут переменная задается. Хотя могу ошибаться. Однако указанный скрипт у меня выводит только один каталог и все. Что не так?

Мне нужно получить список файлов и папок в нем.
[Non-recursive os.walk()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4117588/non-recursive-os-walk)

Comment: os.listdir?

Answer (score 2):

```
for path, dirs, files in os.walk(.....)
```

path - текущий каталог куда смотрит цикл (строка)
dirs - массив имен директорий в текущем каталоге
files - массив имен файлов в текущем каталоге

```
for path, dirs, files in os.walk(...):
   for fname in files:
       print os.path.join(path, fname)
```